# How to upload form data to google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

To upload data to the datastore I use this java code :

```
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Entity entity = new Entity("mydetail");
entity.setProperty("entry", "entry");
ds.put(entity);
```

For uploading form based data is this the correct method of uploading data, ie using similar code above or is there another API I should be using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this the direct API to the AppEngine Datastore.

You can also use JDO interface which allows for directly storing a Java object without dealing with the Datastore API:

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;

@PersistenceCapable
public class MyDetail {
    // ...
    @Persistent
    private String entry;
    // ...
```

There is also the JPA interface. Both of the interfaces are described on the [App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) website.

The [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) interface is very easy and for many situations easier. It is not part of the official SDK.

You can use whichever makes more sense for you application.